# Vba to create a new column and insert array formula

Tags: vba, excel

My below code is the slowest `sub` in my workbook. I can't set it to put the Array in immediatley, because the mode is calculated incorrectly (calculates for just one site no)

Is there a way to cut this down without breaking the fully functioning code?

```
Sub ModeColumn()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, rng As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
Set rng = ws.Cells(2, 15)
    ws.Cells(1, 15) = "MODE"
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                  'Finds the bottom populated row

    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 15), ws.Cells(LastRow, 15))
           .Formula = "=IFERROR(MODE(IF(RC[-2]=AllSites,R2C12:R" & LastRow & "C12)),""N/A"")"
           .FormulaArray = .FormulaR1C1
    End With


End Sub
```

Here's what it looks like working

[image]
[image]

So above we can see that the selection works perfectly, but if I use the array formula right away, I get a lot of errors - so my time saving, breaks the expected result
And here's what it looks like if I just use "array" straight away

[image]
[image]

This is based on the following code

```
With ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 15), ws.Cells(LastRow, 15))
       .FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(MODE(IF(RC[-2]=AllSites,R2C12:R" & LastRow & "C12)),""N/A"")"
End With
```

P.S I *cannot* (by request) use Excel Tables to make this easier

Comment: Just from the images in the top you have `$L$2:$L$3774` and below it you have `$L$2:$L7`. Seems like something was done that's not reflected in your code. Was there a manual edit?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned - the last 2 images are from the "record macro" feature, where I added in the Array Forumla after

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect the bad code correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually with mass-Formula, I would recommend judicious use of the [`Application.Calculation` property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculation) to ensure that you don't recalculate for every cell (3773 times in your example!) - but, in this case I am **also** going to recommend using the [`Range.FillDown` method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown) instead of assigning the Array Formula to every cell in the range.

(Also the [`MODE` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mode-function-e45192ce-9122-4980-82ed-4bdc34973120) is only included for Legacy Support, and has been replaced by the [`MODE.SNGL`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/mode-sngl-function-f1267c16-66c6-4386-959f-8fba5f8bb7f8) and [`MODE.MULT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mode-mult-function-50fd9464-b2ba-4191-b57a-39446689ae8c) functions)

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Do not recalculate formula until we say so!
With ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 15), ws.Cells(LastRow, 15))
       .Cells(1,1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(MODE.SNGL(IF($M2=AllSites,$L$2:$L$" & LastRow & ")),""N/A"")" 'Set the Array Formula for the first cell
       '.Cells(1,1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(MODE.SNGL(IF(RC[-2]=AllSites,R2C12:R" & LastRow & "C12)),""N/A"")"'In R1C1 Notation
       .FillDown 'Copy the Array Formula down to the end
End With
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'Reset Calculation Mode
```

(For comparison - running your method on 99999 rows of junk data took me 105 seconds.  Using the `.Filldown` method on the same data took 29 seconds, and 99% of that was just waiting for Excel to finish calculating the Worksheet after the functions where in!)

Comment: Hi - thanks for the great insight. Clearly looks like a much better way to run this. I'm not sure what I need to do with `Application.Calculate` as it just gives me a compile error. Apologies for this, I've never used this feature

Comment: Got it, I used `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` instead

Comment: @Badja Yes, I was just about to say that - I typed the wrong one when writing it out for your code.  Sorry!

Comment: Brilliant - this has worked perfectly and saved a LOT of time.. One last thing (if people in future want to see this) could you pelase edit your answer to have the array formula from my question? As yours was likely a placeholder?  `.Cells(1, 1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(MODE.SNGL(IF(RC[-2]=AllSites,R2C12:R" & LastRow & "C12)),""N/A"")" ` Thanks ever so much for your help

Comment: @Badja The [`Range.FormulaArray` property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray) is known to sometimes have... *issues*... with `R1C1` notation, which is why I rewrote `"=IFERROR(MODE.SNGL(IF(RC[-2]=AllSites,R2C12:R" & LastRow & "C12)),""N/A"")"` as `"=IFERROR(MODE.SNGL(IF($M2=AllSites,$L$2$L$" & LastRow & ")),""N/A"")"` (the same, but in `A1` notation)

Comment: I believe there's a notation issue with your formula, I'm unable to run it, could you have a look as I can't pick it up. It will have something to do with my `C12` at the end, but I'm stumped as yours should work, looking at it

Comment: I was missing the colon from `"$L$2:$L$" & LastRow`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that... Thanks for your help!